# How can I get the id of the item that is selected in the select option?

Tags: php, mysql, post, get, primary-key

`enter code here`I want to get the id of the selected item from the database when the user selects an item from the select option in an html form using the php language.
`

```
$query = "select * from Courses";
$results = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

`This id is in the courses table

I want to get the id of the selected item from the database when the user selects an item from the select option in an html form using the php language. [this is image about select option that exsit html form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg3Sq.jpg)

```
<div class="user_profile">
    <div class="div">

        <form action="UserPanel.php" class="userinfo" method="post">
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $user_data['username'] ?>" name="name" placeholder="نام کاربری">

            <input type="email" value="<?php echo $user_data['email'] ?>" name="email" placeholder="پست الکترونیکی">
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $user_data['national_code'] ?>" name="ncode" placeholder="کد ملی ">


            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $user_data['date_of_birth'] ?>" name="date_of_birth" placeholder="تاریخ تولد">

            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $user_data['education'] ?>" name="education" placeholder=" تحصیلات">
            <span>عنوان دوره آموزشی </span>
            <select name="courses" id="course" style="width:220px;color:white;font-size:14px">
                <option value="">دوره خود را انتخاب کنید</option>
                <?php foreach ($result as $key => $value) { ?>
                    <option value="<?= $value['Course_Name']; ?>"><?= $value['Course_Name']; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
            
            <div class="btns">

                <button class="btn" name="update">ویرایش اطلاعات </button>
                <button class="btn">حذف </button>
                <button class="btn" name="register"> ثبت نهایی </button>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
```

but this is an error
[undefined array key id_Crs.....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52csG.jpg)

this is code for insert into
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
$id = $user_data['id'];

```
// insert into database and table register

$insert = "INSERT INTO registration(user_id,id_Crs) VALUES ('$id','$id_crs')";
if (mysqli_query($con, $insert)) {
    $message = "Registration";
} else {
    $message = "Error: registering failed $insert." . mysqli_error($con);
}
```

}

Comment: What is the HTML of your form? ([Edit] your question and paste there)

Comment: without html and php code we can't do anything

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<?php
  $query = "select * from Courses";
$results = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    # you can get id 
    ?><option value="<?=$res["id"];?>"><?=$res["name"];?></option>
<?php } '>
```

Comment: i want get  id_Crs and Course_Name?  do this code is correct?

Comment: You retrieve the data (it will be an array) you will iterate the array and retrieve the id_crs and the name

Comment: That does not include the id for "_when the user selects an item from the select option_" though

Comment: Actually, I need the id_crs of the selected item to be inserted in another table. How can I get it? Only the id of the selected item. this is code insert into....if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $id = $user_data['id'];
    
  

    // insert into database and table register

    $insert = "INSERT INTO registration(user_id,id_Crs) VALUES ('$id','$id_crs')";
    if (mysqli_query($con, $insert)) {
        $message = "Registration";

Comment: @Cisco_dev Thank you for your reply, this code outputs id_crs and course_name together, but my only goal is the id of the selected item, which means that when an item is selected from the select option, we only see its name, but its id_crs is also received so that I can get this id_crs put in another table

Comment: Can i see your code ?

Comment: Or you can write on my whatsapp +22898852436

Comment: @Cisco_dev ok thank you bro I calling with you in a few minutes .please wait...